# Create Certificates for PKINIT-based Kerberos login on Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, certificate, kerberos, sssd

I'm trying to set-up a PKINIT-based Kerberos login on a Active Directory. The login shall be performed using sssd on Linux. However, the kerberos server does not accept the client certificate. We receive an error with event ID 21: Certificate for user REALM/Domainuser is not valid on the server and sssd says: Client name mismatch.

The certificates were created with the following procedure on a different Linux machine:

- `openssl req -new -key keyfile.pem -out reqfile.pem -subj 
  "/CN=Domainuser/O=AAA/C=DE/OU=BBB"`
- `env REALM=REALM.local CLIENT=Domainuser openssl x509 \
  -CAkey ../ca_privkey.pem -CA ../ca_cert.pem -req -in reqfile.pem \
  -extensions client_cert -extfile extensions.client \
  -days 365 -out certfile.pem`

We installed the AD CA on the Windows Server that hosts the AD itself. We exported the certificte of this CA to the Linux machine and stored its private key and certificate in the `ca_privkey.pem` and `ca_cert.pem`files to use it with `openssl`.

The `client_cert` we used during signature creation was created using the template suggested by sssd. The only thing we added is the `crlDistributionPoints` option to include the CRL of the CA:

```
[client_cert]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage=digitalSignature,keyEncipherment,keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage=1.3.6.1.5.2.3.4
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
issuerAltName=issuer:copy
subjectAltName=otherName:1.3.6.1.5.2.2;SEQUENCE:princ_name
crlDistributionPoints=URI:http://link-to-CRL-of-CA

[princ_name]
realm=EXP:0,GeneralString:${ENV::REALM}
principal_name=EXP:1,SEQUENCE:principal_seq

[principal_seq]
name_type=EXP:0,INTEGER:1
name_string=EXP:1,SEQUENCE:principals

[principals]
princ1=GeneralString:${ENV::CLIENT}
```

The realm used for the authentication is REALM.local (equal to the AD Domain). The environment variables `REALM` and `CLIENT` are set to `REALM.LOCAL` and `pkuser` during certificate creation and the user `pkuser` also exists in the AD (Password-based login is possible).

I have no clue why the authentication is not successful. Do you have any ideas what might be wrong in the configuration or give me a hint s.t. Windows prints a more detailed error message? Note, that `certutil -verify -urlfetch certfile.pem` is able to validate the whole certificate chain and does not print any errors when executed with the `Administrator` command on the AD server.

I assume that there are some configuration errors on the Windows Server. This is the first time I configured a Windows Server ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, we figured out what the problem was. Windows AD requires additional extended key usage fields to allow the authentication.

You have to add `1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2` and `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2`.

Further, the SAN must be set to: `otherName:1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3;UTF8:<client-name>@<realm>`